# VBA Code to throw prompt

Tags: vba, excel

Need your help on modifying the code or code that will help me do complete my task.
Its a protected workbook with VBA. I have a drop down on sheet1 in B18,D20,K11 and M46 and list of values in each drop down's.

When user changes the values in drop-down B18 and D20, I want to throw a prompt with "ok" and "cancel". User selects "ok" it should run a Module 1 ( which renames sheet).

Two things I am failing to achieve.
1. I **don't want** to throw prompt if user changes any other drop down values apart from 2 cells mentioned above,.
2. When clicked "OK" it should run module 1.

Please suggest if you have better code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rNg As Range

Set rNg = Range("B18", "D20")
MsgBox "Please click Calculate Button", vbOKOnly, "Calculate button"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

(don't understand why you want to check if the user pressed "**OK**" since you are using a `MsgBox` with `vbOKOnly` and he has no other option)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rNg                         As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range
Dim message                     As Integer

' modify here to the Range you need monitored
Set rNg = Range("B18", "D20")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, rNg)

If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    message = MsgBox("Please click Calculate Button", vbOKOnly, "Calculate button")
    If message = vbOK Then
        Call Module1 ' or your Module / Function name
    End If
Else
   'Do Nothing if outside range

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Code I provided was written by previous user. I am new to VBA. I am not sure, if he had completed the code or he was half way through.

I tried to use your code, I get an error in the line Call Module 1. Error states "Expected Variable or Procedure, not module.

Fyi, Module 1 has Sub Calculatesheet().

Please suggest

Comment: @Manu did you read the comment next to the line ? you need to modify the name of `Call Module1` to your function name. what is the name of your module or function you want to call ?

Comment: My bad, I replaced with the function and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the wright method, but you could use a UserForm to create custom prompts. And this is the way i do it, because for me it gives a better control on what i need to do.

Suppose if you create a userform with ok and cancel button, then you trigger the userform on the dropdown value change,

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Then write the codes for ok and cancel button clicks

```
Private Sub Ok_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    MsgBox "clicked ok"
End Sub

Private Sub cancel_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    MsgBox "clicked cancel"
End Sub
```